# AWS elastic IP vs public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-ip

I am new to AWS and tried to create an EC2 instance.

I have a domain and ready to modify the A record to the associated EC2 instance.

I found an article that said an elastic IP is required for associating a production domain.

But AWS provides a public IP and it is accessible on the public internet too (i know it changes after restart, just assuming its okay to modify the A record after the machine is restarted - actually it is not restart very often).

In this case, is it a must that to assign an elastic IP to the instance (this instance contains no load balancing, it is only a simple single instance)?

If yes, why is it necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Elastic IP (EIP) is not necessary provided that you understand the limitations of public IPs. You may not reboot your instance, but AWS might for any number of reasons. This means that the public IP address could change when you are not expecting it.

When an EIP is assigned to a running EC2 instance, there are no charges for the EIP e.g. it is free. Therefore why go thru the hassle of needing to monitor your public IP address.